# What does ReactJs offer that Polymer doesn't?

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, polymer, components

I know how to use Polymer fairly well, and am embarking on a django project employing Polymer for webcomponents. I want to get on the bandwagon of "popular web application frameworks" like Angular and React, which are said to be distinct from Polymer's main purpose. But so far it seems as if all React does is create custom components itself. So on top of creating individual components, what does React offer that Polymer doesn't?

Comment: I'm not into React but the biggest difference will likely be Virtual DOM.

Comment: You may want to look at answers to this question on *Programmers*: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/225400/pros-and-cons-of-facebooks-react-vs-web-components-polymer